# Show results of a growing database in real time on website with data security issues

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, data-security, r-server

I want to create a website where i can show descriptive tables and graphics. Nearly every day the database is growing. So i would like to have a real time calculation or at least a daily update. I thought about an r server with shiny or mardown. That connects the database and generates the output. I have never done this before so i am not sure how well the database is secured.
Because the main Problem is these are patient data. So for datasecurity issues it must be ensured that the Users can not see or access the database under any circumstances. They should only be able to view the cummulated results and graphics.

This is a project on a cancer research register and the research is very fast at the moment so we want to make sure that all results go out asap. If we could make that work with all data being secured this would have a high impact.

I am at the very beginning of this so the database exists and has many variables for thousands of patients. But when i don't make sure the database is safe, i don't even need to start creating the ui.

I welcome any ideas on how to do this and any idea of how to improve it or any other ideas.

Comment: Very General question, probably not best suited for a single answer. Perhaps you can move this to the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199379/r-shiny-cancer-research-app

Comment: it sounds more like a architecture question on software engineering site, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124867/where-should-i-ask-software-architecture-design-questions

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Generate the accumulated data + graphics on a system that is not publically accessible.
- Copy the generated data+graphics to your web site, so that they can be displayed.
- Hire a security analysis firm to verify that there are no exploitable issues in your implementation.

The latter suggestion might be fairly expensive, but is a pittance compared to your potential liability should private patient date be exposed.